# Downvote on a question did not cause reputation loss **for the asker of the question**

Tags: support, questions, reputation, downvotes

I noticed this in somebody's reputation log:

[image]

This was for a question a person asked. Normally, if somebody downvoted that person's question, I'd expect to see a `-2` in red; however, this is missing.

Why didn't that person lose 2 rep as expected?

Comment: Maybe because the OP had 1 rep to start with?

Comment: That's what I thought at first; but as you can see by the time stamps, they earned rep (+5) before the downvote occurred.

Comment: @cppprog: no, they did not, that view lists oldest event first (grouped per post).

Comment: 20:28 > 20:16, the grouping may be confusing to you. :)

Comment: oops I thought that said 20:14 instead of 21:14

Comment: I am not sure but I would expect something else here. If you check the time stamp of the downvote and the first upvote (20:16). I would expect it to be from the same user. 
In my guess the user missclicked on the downvote. And not just retraced his vote but changed it to an upvote. That way the downvote occured (resulting in -2) was taken back (resulting in +2) and an upvote occured (resulting in +5) in more or less the same time.

Comment: Hah, so if you want your downvotes on a question from a 1-rep user to have an impact, don't cast them until someone else has upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

If that person had just 1 point reputation they would not have lost any more.

All the other votes are *after* that initial downvote at 20:16. The grouping in the view you took a screenshot of lists per-post events from newer to older.